# Jquery AJAX with JSON form value update

Tags: json, jquery, asp-classic

I thought I was heading in the right direction here. But somewhere, information overload set in.

Simple task: I want to have a user select something from a drop down, and have jquery populate the form cells from that selection.  The selection is sending an ID request to my ASP script, which is returning the data in a JSON format. But Jquery isn't populating the form at all.

Here is my Jquery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#list-avail-reps").change( function() {
        var rep_id = $(this).val();
        var datastring = "ID="+rep_id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: datastring,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "sales-reps.asp",
        success: function(data) {
            var rep_name=json.rep_name
            var rep_cell=json.rep_cell
            var rep_email=json.rep_email
            var rep_branch=json.rep_branch
            var branch_id=json.branch_id
            $("#rep_name").val(rep_name);
            $("#rep_cell").val(rep_cell);
            $("#rep_branch").val(rep_name);
            $("#rep_email").val(rep_email);
            $("#rep_active").val('1');
            $("#rep_login_ID").val(rep_id);
            $("#branch_ID").val(branch_ID);
        }
    });//end ajax command
    }); //end of listener
});//end document function
</script>
```

My JSON output is the following:

```
[
{
"rep_name":"Name here",
"rep_cell":"Number here",
"rep_branch":"More info",
"rep_email":"email here",
"branch_id":"5"
}
]
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `json.rep_name` ? >> you should use `data.rep_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `data` instead of `json`.

**Example**:

`data.rep_email` versus `json.rep_email`

The data that is returned appears to be an array.  So you will need to iterate over your array (or assume an index of 0).

**Example**:

```
var rep_email = data[0].rep_email
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rep_email = data[i].rep_email;
}
```

Comment: Took a few code tweaks to get it, missing semi-colons, but between those and the data (no array) I succeeded.  Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

You are being returned an array of objects. To access these values, you need to first select the first index of the array:

```
var rep_name=data[0].rep_name
var rep_cell=data[0].rep_cell
var rep_email=data[0].rep_email
var rep_branch=data[0].rep_branch
var branch_id=data[0].branch_id
```

Also, you are returned `data` not `json`

Answer (score 0):

var obj = JSON.parse(data); var rep_name=obj[0].rep_name

Comment: Please explain your code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: success: function(data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data); var rep_name=obj[0].rep_name; $("#rep_name").val(rep_name);
        }